Let $n \mid p-1$ with $p$ a prime and $E$ the splitting field of $x^n - a$ for $a \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$. Find $\mathrm{Gal}(E / \mathbb{F}_p)$.
In particular:
Let $n \mid p-1$ with $p$ a prime and $E$ the splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $x^n - a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$. Show that $\mathrm{Gal}(E / \mathbb{F}) \cong \langle a^{\frac{p-1}{n}} \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{F}_p^\times$.
I can show that $\mathrm{Gal}(E / \mathbb{F}_p)$ embeds into $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$, and clearly $\langle a^{\frac{p-1}{n}} \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{F}_p^\times$, but I'm not entirely sure how to show that they are isomorphic. I thought about showing that $|\mathrm{Gal}(E / \mathbb{F}_p)| = o(a^{\frac{p-1}{n}})$ but wasn't able to. A small hint would be appreciated.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^n-a$ in $E$. If $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a conjugate, what can you say about $\sigma(\alpha)/\alpha$ ?
